# Probability in logistic regression

Tags: probability, logistic

I come across a practice where the logit (Intercept + beta* variables) is once again input as a independant variable in a single variable logistic regression against dependant variable to get intercept ($I$) and a beta ($B_0$). Finally, probability is calculated: $\frac{1}{1+e^{-(I+B_0\text{logit})}}$.

Why is this done -- since probability can be directly calculated from the logit in the first step?

Comment: Are there different dependent variables in the two models?

Comment: Can you post where you're coming across this?

Comment: No different dependant variables.. It is the same default variable. I come across this in a prob of default model for auto loan portfolio

Answer (score 2):

"Why is this done" -- I don't think it *is* done ordinarily.  I don't see any purpose for it.  As you point out, there's another standard, correct way to calculate the probability of each case being "1" on Y.  The kind of feedback you describe just seems to confuse things.